# How to debug iOS 9 extensions

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslog, ios-extensions

Is there a way I can debug my networkextension (NEPacketTunnelProvider)? .

I use NSLog but not use for extension (only for container app).  I found system log in window -> devices, but only have crash logs.

so I can only debug by breakpoint（debug -> attach) . but it's really really annoying me for a long time. Can I view log (NSLog) in somewhere?

Comment: You can use `Console` app in the mac to get all the logs. Make sure you select a proper device to check the logs. It will print all the mac logs as well.

Comment: It only display mac's log, not real device (phone)

Comment: You can use the XCode>Devices>Select Your Device and check. If you can't find it their, then I don't think it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can.. 
First Start Your container App.
Switch to Your Extension App in xCode.
Go To Debug and choose attach to process..
Put the breakpoints to debug than